# ONTOP plugin protege - reasoning and query answering

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am new to using ONTOP in protege and I have a question about its use.

I have a small ontology that contains a class called OnConnectedState and an individual of that type "on_connected_state_1". With the following axiom: "satisfies some OnConnectedPrecondition".

When I use a Hermit reasoner, and create a DL query, I can query "satisfies some OnConnectedPrecondition" and the query will return my individual "on_connected_state_1".

Using ontop, I want to be able to query this information. So I run the ONTOP reasoner with no errors and have written the following sparql query:

PREFIX proc:  http://www.semanticweb.org/procedure-ontology#
SELECT ?s ?y
WHERE {
    ?s proc:satisfies ?y
}

However, the result comes up blank and there is no SQL translation.

What am I missing here? I am unclear why my "on_connected_state_1" individual does not appear.

Comment: why do you want to use Ontop if you have all in the ontology? how do you run the query? Ontop uses the ontology as schema (if you provide it as such) and queries the configured SQL database by rewriting SPARQL to SQL (optionally with reasoning by means of query rewriting/expansion) - so, can you please provide more details and the workfow you have in mind?

Comment: Hi there! thanks for your response.

I'd like to use ONTOP to map to a mySQL database but am using individuals in protege to test the concept with some dummy data before writing all my mappings. Could the fact that I'm not currently mapping to a SQL database perhaps be causing the problem?

I am currently running queries through the Ontop SPARQL tab in Protege and am able to query the dummy data successfully with more basic queries (i.e. retrieving all instances of a class).

Comment: I'm not fully sure but I think it would work with the data from the SQL database, yes. I mean, the workflow of Ontop is SPARQL -> use SQL database mappings -> generate SQL query -> query SQL database -> create the SPARQL solution bindings out of the returned SQL rows. It might also be because Ontop is no full OWL DL reasoner compared to HermiT

Comment: I just tried with mappings to the database with no luck. It's possible that the problem might be the expressiveness of the reasoner. The axiom "satisfies some OnConnectedPrecondition" is only specified at the class level in the ontology, not at the individual level (I would like to avoid defining it at the individual level). However, I'm pretty sure this type of query is within the capabilities of an OWL 2 QL reasoner (but I could be wrong).

Comment: yes, it's definitely in OWL QL - did you enable the Quest reasoner in the reasoner menu?

Comment: I enabled the Ontop 3.0.1 reasoner